# pick the most relevant word for each category of texts : Bayesian approach or?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

10 years after taking an probability theory, now I am dealing with a practical situation. I think my problem is quite basic, but I was stuck and am writing a post here.

Consider the set of vocabularies $V$ and the set of documents $D$. Each document is categorized into 10 categories $\{c_1, \cdots, c_{10}\}$. $i \ne j \implies c_i \cap c_j = \varnothing$, and $\cup_{i =1}^{10}c_i = D$. What I want to do is to pick up some word sets which are most relevant to certain category.

My first idea is to write down a conditional probability $f(v, d) = P(d \in c_0 | v \in d)$ where $v$ is a word in $V$ and $d \in D$.

Here my intend is to calculuate $P(v \in d)$ based on counting, as $P(v \in d) = (\text{number of times $v$ appeared in $d$})/|d|$.

I think the cond. prob. $f(v, d)$ represents the probability of document $d$ being member of category $c_1$ under the condition of $v \in d$. My strategy is to pick up word $v$ of highest values $f_1(v) = E_d[P(d \in c_1 | v \in d)]$.

But what does this equation mean? I gave it a try to write down:

\begin{align*} f_1(v) & = \frac{1}{|D|} \sum_{d \in D} P(d \in c_1 | w \in d) = \frac{1}{|D|} \sum_{d \in D} \dfrac{P(d \in c_1 \text{ and } w \in d)}{P(w \in d)} = \\ 
& = \frac{1}{|D|} \sum_{d \in D} \dfrac{P(w \in d | d \in c_1 )P(d \in c_1)}{P(w \in d)}\\ 
& = \frac{1}{|D|} \sum_{d \in c_1} \dfrac{P(w \in d | d \in c_1 )}{P(w \in d)}  = \frac{1}{|D|} \sum_{d \in c_1} \dfrac{P(w \in d )}{P(w \in d)} = |c_1|/|D|
\end{align*}
which is an absurd.

Could somebody give me an advice? Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by $f_1(v)=E[P(d \in c_1\mid v \in d)]$. You write that the expectation is calculated "over document $d$", so presumably you mean $E_d[P(d \in c_1\mid v \in d)]$. But that would only make sense if $P(d \in c_1\mid v \in d)$ were a function of $d$. But if it's a function of $d$, and also of $v$ (since the left-hand side $f_1(v)$ is a function of $v$), then there's no random variable left to which the probability might refer (assuming that the intention is not to treat $c_1$ as a random variable).

Comment: I suggest that you make more explicit in each step what the random variables are, what their distributions are, etc.

Comment: @joriki I want to calculuate $P(v \in d)$ by naive counting $\text{number of occurrence of $v$ in $d$}/{\sum_{w \in V} \text{number of occurrence of $w$ in $d$} }$. 

Is $E_d[ p(v, d)] = \int_D p(v, d) d(d)$ an absurd? (notation $dd$ sucks...)

Comment: That's not any clearer to me than what you wrote in the original post. I doubt that this is an efficient approach at clarifying things. I repeat my suggestion to make explicit in each step (including in the above comment) what the random variables are and what their distributions are. E.g., in $P(v\in d)$ above, is $v$ random? If so, what is its distribution? Or is $d$ random? If so, what is its distribution? Or are they both random? If so, what is their joint distribution?

Comment: Now I think i get the point you are pointing out. let me think about my situation. thanks